# lack of service instance in app.module file

Tags: angular

I need to use a service to configure a module inside app.module, just like that:

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    targetModule.forRoot({
      'var1': environmentService.var1,
      
    }),
    anotherModule,
  ],
```

how to create an instance of EnvironmentService in this case? EnvironmentService is "providedIn: root" service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `inject` from `@angular/core` module

```js
    import {NgModule, inject} from '@angular/core';
    
    const injectedVal = inject(environmentService).var1;

    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      targetModule.forRoot({
        'var1': injectedVal,
      
      }),
      anotherModule,
   ],
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, However, I receive a: "core.js:4745 Uncaught Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4745)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:4755)
    at Module.53952 (app.module.ts:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.7160 (environment.ts:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at __webpack_exec__ (main.js:9114)
    at main.js:9115
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (chunk loaded:23)
    at main.js:9116" error on the console after transpiling

Comment: what is your angular version?

Comment: My friend. You inspired me to solve it. I've made: const injector = Injector.create({
  providers: [{
    provide: EnvironmentService,
  }],
}); and then:
injector.get(EnvironmentService).someProperties :)  Thank you very much. Withoout inject from you side I would not do it. I use new version of Ng